# NullPointerException In Send Https Request With jetty Http Client

Tags: java, https, httpclient, jetty-9

I am using Jetty HTTP Client (v9.2.5) To Send HTTP Request
It is Work Fine For HTTP Request {Post,Get,...}
But When I send HTTPS Request Post I See This

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:642)
```

My Function Is

```
private Object sendHttpPOSTRequest(String url, List<Header> headers,
        String content, HttpMethod method) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.setMaxConnectionsPerDestination(16);
        client.setAddressResolutionTimeout(5000);
        client.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        client.setMaxRedirects(3);
        client.setFollowRedirects(true);
        client.setExecutor(_executor);
        client.start();
        Request req = client.POST(url).content(
                new StringContentProvider(content));
        if (headers != null)
            req = setHeaders(req, headers);
        req.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

        return req.send();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed";
    }

}
```

Whats Wrong?

Comment: Where is your client initialized?

Comment: where is your _executor defined?

Comment: Define at the Top of class
private ExecutorService _executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Answer (score 7):

For HTTPS you have to use the httpclient initialization like the following way:

```
// Instantiate and configure the SslContextFactory
SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();

// Instantiate HttpClient with the SslContextFactory
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);

// Configure HttpClient, for example:
httpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);

// Start HttpClient
httpClient.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use (see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http-client.html):

```
// Instantiate and configure the SslContextFactory
SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();

// Instantiate HttpClient with the SslContextFactory
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);

// Configure HttpClient, for example:
httpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);

// Start HttpClient
httpClient.start();
```